# Getting pk of selected record from datagridview in another form

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

When I perform the getPkRowReport() it works correctly if I am using the value on the same form (form1). If I need the pk for Form 2 it always defaults to the top row and never the row i had selected before I launch form 2. If I look at form 1 after I launch form 2 the correct row is selected but I am still getting the pk for the top record. Any help would be appreciated.

Form 1:

```
    private int pkFromReport;
    public int PkFromReport
    {
        get
        {
            pkFromReport = getPkRowReport();
            return pkFromReport;
        }
    } 

    private int getPkRowReport()
    {
        if (dgvReportGrid.CurrentRow != null)
        {
            //get selected row index
            int index = this.dgvReportGrid.CurrentRow.Index;
            //get pk of selected row using index
            string cellValue = dgvReportGrid["rptNo", index].Value.ToString();
            //change pk string to int
            int pKey = Int32.Parse(cellValue);

            return pKey;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Form 2:

```
private frmMain mainForm = new frmMain();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = mainForm.PkFromReport.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that CurrentRow returns the SelectedRow. This property could be affected by a form losing/gaining focus. Perhaps try to find the row you want using the .SelectedRows collection of a DataGridView?

Comment: Collections are newer to me so that may take me some time to figure out. I did try making the datagridview public just for testing reasons and put all the code on form 2. I still get the same result. Even if I change the record on form1 after launching form 2 while debugging I always get the pk of the top record..

Comment: I have tried datagridview.focus() when loading the second form but that didnt help.

Comment: Beginner mistake by me... I am now just passing the pk to the other form when launching it and it works fine instead of using a property on the original form. Thanks to all those that contributed.

Answer (score 1):

[CurrentRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow.aspx) gets the row containing the current cell.
When your form loses focus, your selected row is no longer the current row.

You should use the `SelectedRows` collection to get your currently selected row. Since you plan to have only one selected row, change your code like this:

```
private int getPkRowReport()
{
    if (dgvReportGrid.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        //get selected row index
        int index = this.dgvReportGrid.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        //get pk of selected row using index
        string cellValue = dgvReportGrid["rptNo", index].Value.ToString();
        //change pk string to int
        int pKey = Int32.Parse(cellValue);

        return pKey;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I made your modifications and now I just return -1 for every selection.

Comment: Look at the code, what does that say? You don't have any selected rows. SelectedRows.Count is 0. Debug and verify.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The count should be greater than 0 when I am selecting a row correct? When I click on a row it goes straight to the else.